# couchbase community 6.5 and SDK 3 fill memory

Tags: node.js, memory, sdk, memcached, couchbase

how can I limit Memcached memory usage,
in couchbase community 6.5 and SDK 3 its fill memory and after restart the service memory is free.
another question is my data in couchbase totally is 100mb and Memcache fills 14gb memory whats that reason?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more context? Seems odd that this is happening because you can limit memory usage when you create the bucket

Comment: @deniswsrosa
I found this issue, thanks its problem of sdk and i change some flow of that.